# Python list comprehension to get max() of each list column

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have following list of lists:

```
lst = [[1,3], [3,4], [2,7], [6,5]]
```

How do I create "oneliner" to get list of max() of each "column"?

So, for the example above, the resulting list should be following: `[6,7]`, where 6 is the maximum of "column 0" and 7 is the maximum of "column 1".

Comment: Have you tried without a one-liner?

Comment: Start by writing something that solves the problem. Then try to massage it smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) which splits the pairs into two separate tuples:

```
>>> lst = [[1,3], [3,4], [2,7], [6,5]]

>>> list(zip(*lst))
[(1, 3, 2, 6), (3, 4, 7, 5)]
```

So, overall:

```
>>> [max(v) for v in zip(*lst)]
[6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume not all "rows" will necessarily contain the same number of columns, despite the given example, we can get the minimum "column" bound with: `min(map(len, lst))`.

We can use this to iterate over the columns:  `for col_num in range(min(map(len, lst)))`.

And we can iterate over rows with `for row in lst`, so putting this together:

```
[[row[col_num] for row in lst] for col_num in range(min(map(len, lst)))]
# => [[1, 3, 2, 6], [3, 4, 7, 5]]
```

But we just need the maximum, and `max` can be fed a generator expression instead of a list to keep this a bit more memory-efficient, so:

```
[max(row[col_num] for row in lst) for col_num in range(min(map(len, lst)))]
# => [6, 7]
```